# Redundant parameter in Spring controller method?

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have *createForm*, which is displayed to user. As you can presume it is empty form and the user has to fill it with information. In my controller I have, the following code:

```
     @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "mode=create")
     public ModelAndView showCreatePage(@Nonnull @ModelAttribute("createForm") ApplicationCreateForm form)
                throws ClientException {
            return customMethod("ApplicationController/create");
        }
```

We do not need to populate the form with the information to be present to the user all fields are empty, so why I need to specify in the metod *ApplicationCreateForm form* as method parameter? Is it unnecessary, or Spring use in some way?

Comment: You need a way to construct a model object, if it isn't there the form wouldn't render. Instead of adding it as a metho argument you could also add a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` to create to model object.

Comment: OK, but in the jsp file for the form:
<jsp:useBean id="ceateForm" scope="request"
             class="com.example.categoryCreateForm"/> in this article:http://www.studytonight.com/jsp/usebean-tag.php, say that if(myBean=null)
{
   myBean = new PersonBean();, so if the form is null default will be created. I still do not understand. Please can you explain in more details.

Comment: You are confusing plain JSP with Spring you shouldn't be using `jsp:useBean`.

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit confused about this situation, so for that reason I ask here. I am wondering how I can break my code to prove that this argument is necessary? If I remove the argument the create empty form is displayed as usual.

Comment: It will work but you shouldn't do that. You now have logic in your view, your views should be dumb yours contains logic. You are mixing plain JSP programming (whichyou basically shouldnt be doing) and spring. If you use Spring then use the framework don't work around it (which is what you are doing). To break your code remove the useBean stuff from your jsp and remove the argumetn. Then your code will break telling you that there is no attribute called 'createForm'.

Comment: My purpose is not to remove the argument but to understand if its place is there. Now I have argument and jsp in which I tell:<jsp:useBean id="ceateForm" scope="request" class="com.example.categoryCreateForm"/>. So you tell that it is not good to have such bean definition in the jsp?

Comment: Exactly. Your view should be dumb, your model should be prepared by the controller now you have 2 places which prepare a model.

Comment: Big thanks, @ M. Deinum